# Does Power BI report subscription allow workspace owner to manage the subscriptions?

Tags: powerbi

I have workspace with couple of reports and a dataset. The reports are published into an app that is consumed by end users.

Couple of users have asked me let them have an email copy of the report every Monday morning.

I am looking at the following options:

1. Allow user to subscribe to the report
2. As an admin I can subscribe users to a report
3. Use Power automate to create a recurring workflow to export the report and email

Using option 3 I have centralized control (in the Power automate workflow) over the report export time, and email recipients.

Does option 1 and 2 allow me to be able to control/manage the subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In the workspace you can see and manage all the subscriptions to the report, whether created by you or the users.  This is documented here: [Manage subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe?tabs=creator#manage-subscriptions)

Comment: Say I as an admin configure subscription (via power bi portal) for another user, then will the user get an email with RLS as per my account or his account? Power automate gives me the option to choose the RLS role prior to report Export/email.

Comment: Subscriptions created by app aren't shown in the workspace subscriptions section `Workspace admins cannot manage subscriptions created by another user in an app (as opposed to a workspace). Subscriptions created within apps are saved to a user's My workspace and admins do not have access to users' My workspaces.`